# How do i create a json object from an API response

Tags: outsystems

I am trying to consume a bitbucket API which returns me the contents of a file in a repository. However, the response is not your typical JSON format but it is in plain text (basically a string with all the contents in that file).

For example:

### text file in repository (dotted lines represent the text file)

| a = 90 |
| B = 70 |
|        |

---

response:
"a=90\nb=70"

How am i able to convert this response to a json format after consuming the API? I want the format to be something like this (so that i would be able to drag the fields into the UI):

{'a':90, 'b':70}

Answer (score 0):

My company have some partners sending some strange patterns like this.

If the repsonse of API is like "a=90\nb=70" you have a solid pattern so you can split the string into a String List.

For example:

Importing Action ( Fuction ) From [ Text Extension ] - String_Split

String_Split( Text : "a=90\nb=70" , Delimiters : "\n" ) // Generates -> String_Split[0], String_Split[1]

Run Foreach With String_Split and use a NEW Aux_String_Split( Text : String_Split.List.Current.Text.Value , Delimiters : "=" )

Make a condition to certify the Aux_String_Split have two values,

```
If YES, assign to a [ Record (Create a Structure For your JSON) ], and Next Append the Record to a List Record

If NOT, you can append to a Text Variable with a wrong format records.
```

Next Serialize the List. And probably is going be in correct JSON Format, but if you want with ' and not with ", you have to replace in the string the " for '.

I dont know other way. You can search in Forge, but in the backend they are probably make the same what i'm saying.

The better is your API return all time the correct JSON Format, but i understand It's not always possible.

---

If its not this what you want, sorry. Please add a comment with more information, and i try to help.